# OHIF viewer deployed on Azure blob storage does not work for DicomJson

Tags: azure, blob, storage, viewer, ohif

When OHIF viewer is run locally, the dicomjson works well and displays iamges by using following url pattern : http://localhost:3000/viewer/dicomjson?url=https://ohif-dicom-json-example.s3.amazonaws.com/LIDC-IDRI-0001.json.
After that we've built the code for production, copied the content of 'dist' folder to static website. This is done by using Azure blob storage and copying files to '$web' container. When navigated to the static website URL, the initial sample data loads. However when called for the viewer/dicomjson , it fails with error 'Content not found'. Please advise.
Tried static web app deployment to azure using azure blob storage. also tried using web app service. Error still persists.

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]